# Is there any way to save embbeded apache derby database files in jar

Tags: java, database, jar, derby

In my project when i clicked the jar file it extracts embedded database files to near it self.

Is there any way to make them stay in the jar file?

Comment: What is the difference between extracting a folder which contains a derby database to any other folder? Probably nothing. Probably there is info out there how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can package a read-only Derby database into one of the jar files in your classpath, and access it using a different form of the connection URL. See: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/devguide/cdevdvlp24155.html and http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/devguide/cdevdeploy11201.html#cdevdeploy11201

Comment: but i have to insert values to database

Comment: Derby doesn't support updating database data in the jar. I suppose you could: (a) extract your initial DB image from the jar to the filesystem, (b) update/insert data in the filesystem-based database, then (c) re-package the data into the jar. But maybe it's time for you to re-think your application design (or at least reveal more of what you're trying to do, as part of your initial question).

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible, you can put your DB image into any JAR's classpath and access it using:

```
Class.getResourceAsStream()
```

Comment: I cant find any method like getResourceAsStream

Comment: And one more thing; how to put db image into jar's classpath? (I use netbeans)