# Netbeans Derby Database packaged with build of project

Tags: java, netbeans, derby

I have been struggling for about 2 days not trying to figure this out. I have a derby database that is linked to my Project in Netbeans. It has multiple tables. When I try and build the project, if netbeans is still open, it works fine, but if netbeans is closed, it does not connect to the database.

I have looked for ways to package the database with the build but have not seen how to do it. 
I have seen posts that recommend to use this code:

```
CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_EXPORT_TABLE (null, 'YOURTABLE', 'PATHTODUMPFILE', null, null, null)
```

But I have multiple tables, and need it in one file, don't I?

So how can I build the project, and have the derby database packaged with it?

Comment: Will your database be read-only? Or does your application need to update the database while it runs?

Comment: It only needs to be read-only

Comment: For the read-only case, you can use this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7675568/193453